# "There are a piano and a phonograph in the room"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> There are a piano and a phonograph in the room

or

> There is a piano in the room

I am kind of confused between these two.

Answer (score 4):

You should use *is*:

> There *is* a piano and [there *is*] a phonograph[, both of which are] in the room.

However, you should use *are* in the reverse situation:

> The piano and the phonograph *are* in the room.

Notice how in the first example, *there is* is applied to the first object, and therefore we can assume that it applies to the following objects unless otherwise specified. We use *is* because we apply action to object **one at a time**.

In the latter, we do not specify an action for the first object, opting instead to specify an action for all objects at the end. We must use *are* because we are **grouping all objects**.

Hope this helps!